# Intermittent redis connection error: 'UNCERTAIN STATE'

Tags: node.js, redis

Time and time again, we get this error:

```
{ Error: Redis connection to some-redis-server:6379 failed - read ETIMEDOUT
  at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:171:27) errno: 'ETIMEDOUT', code: 'ETIMEDOUT', syscall: 'read' }
{ AbortError: Redis connection lost and command aborted. It might have been processed.
    at RedisClient.flush_and_error (/usr/src/app/node_modules/redis/index.js:362:23)
    at RedisClient.connection_gone (/usr/src/app/node_modules/redis/index.js:664:14)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/redis/index.js:289:14)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:281:20)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:193:13)
    at TCP._handle.close (net.js:614:12)
  code: 'UNCERTAIN_STATE',
  command: 'GET'
  args: [ 'some-key' ] }
```

We are using https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis to access redis.
Some details of the setup:

- Currently 25GB of data stored in Redis
- Writes = a rate of approximately 2MB/sec.
- Max number of concurrent clients connected: 400

I don't know where to really start looking, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: did u get a solution to this?